# Wordpress Oxygen ACF repeater empty condition

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a gallery as an ACF repeater in wordpress.

In Oxygen builder there is a Condition functionality which allows to check some basic stuff, like if some field is blank, if the fields contains something, operators like "==", "!=" etc.

But for repeaters they don't work.
I haven't found a built-in solution to check if a repeater fields is empty or not.

I want to hide the section which holds my gallery if there are no images in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

I have created a custom condition via the Conditions API in Oxygen.

I added this code snippet via the Code Snippets plugin:

```
if( function_exists('oxygen_vsb_register_condition') ) {

oxygen_vsb_register_condition('Repeater empty checker', array('options'=>array(), 'custom'=>true), array('is not empty', 'is empty'), 'check_if_repeater_is_empty', 'Other');

function check_if_repeater_is_empty($value, $operator) {
    if ($operator == "is not empty") {
        return have_rows($value, get_the_ID());
    } else if ($operator == 'is empty') {
        return !have_rows($value, get_the_ID());
    }
}
}
```

And now I have a "Repeater empty checker" in the condition dropdown.
As a value I just enter the name of the fields e.g. **gallery** and it checks if the **gallery** is empty or not.

Comment: Nice. I don't understand how this is not built into core.